# Parsing issue with cocoa pods (1.2.0.beta.1)

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I'm trying to add Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to my project (Xcode 8, Swift 3) using Cocoapods 1.2.0 beta.

I add the pod files

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'
```

then when I pod install, I get this error

```
[!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:
contained in the file located at     /Users/<me>/.cocoapods/repos/master/CocoaPods-version.yml
---
min: 1.0.0
last: 1.2.0.beta.1
prefix_lengths:
- 1
- 1
- 1
```

I searched google and found someone with a similar issue [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6124) and tried installing xcodeproj:1.4.1, and the problem still persists.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening here, and what I can do to successfully install my pods? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'` to `pod 'SwiftyJSON'` and see if that works? Edit: Nevermind, I see the problem is in Cocoapods not the podfile.

Comment: I managed to fix it by installing the most recent version of "psych", then uninstalling psych. Now everything works as expected - I wish I could explain why but I'm very new and don't even know what psych is!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by installing the most recent version of the "psych" gem, then uninstalling psych. Not sure what the issue was, if anyone more knowledgeable would like to pipe in that would be great, otherwise for those reading this question in the future - just uninstall psych.